# Mysql update table A while updating it by event scheduler

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb

let's say I have an event scheduler update_table_A and it simply updates a field name as 'BLAH'

update_table_A

```
update tableA
set name = 'BLAH'
```

this event scheduler takes 5 mins and I want to update tableA while event scheduler is running. but it seems mysql prevents multiple access at the same time.

so my question is

I want to know if mysql provides parallel execution or some way to guarantee concurrency.
thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a INDEX on field 'name' ? and how many records are in the table ?. You can also add **WHERE `name` <> 'BLAH'**

Comment: You can test. Add the Index and the WHERE

Comment: @BerndBuffen oh actually the scheduler is for calculating some scores. but making it faster will only work when there are not so many users. i gotta edit the question to make it clear

Comment: Please show the SQL from the scheduler

Comment: Concurrency <> `prevents multiple access at the same time`

Comment: Are you trying to update all rows of the table?  Don't design the system that way.